# Install Nuget-Dependency with package created over .nuspec file

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I'm trying to create a NuGet-Package from several thrird-party library files. One of these files have a dependency to `System.Drawing.Common`. So I tried to add this as a dependency into my .nuspec file:

```xml
<metadata>
  <id>...</id>
  <version>...</version>
  <authors>...</authors>
  <description>...</description>
  <copyright>...</copyright>
  <tags>...</tags>
  <references>
    <reference file="EntryPointLibrary.dll" />
    <reference file="EntryPointLibrary.xml" />
  </references>
  <dependencies>
    <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp3.1">
      <dependency id="System.Drawing.Common" version="[6.0.0]" />
    </group>
  </dependencies>
</metadata>
```

Unfortunately after installing the Nuget-Package from local the `System.Drawing.Common` is not installed automatically and the System.Drawing.Common.dll is not inside the build folder. I also downloaded the System.Drawing.Common Nuget-Package from [nuget.org](https://nuget.org) and copied this package in my local nuget space.

Comment: Note: I also tried to add the System.Drawing.Common as a [FrameworkAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#framework-assembly-references).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. If you have write the dependencies setting. It should be ok. If it not work. You can try these steps as follow

Step1:Delete your target project obj and bin file.
Step2:Clean your cache. You can enter the common

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

Step3: Rebuild Project
Step4: Install your custom NuGet-Package

You can see the the package detail will have the System.Drawing.Common item

[image]

[image]